Organising DAG Tags in Airflow
I have a two DAGs, example1 and example2. example1 is given tags as ['toy', 'umbrella'] and example1 is given tags as ['toy', 'ball']. In the airflow UI, the tags are displayed as toy umbrella for example1 and ball toy for example2. How to have tags  displayed for example2 as toy ball.
import os
import logging
from datetime import datetime

import yaml

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task

from lib.utils.bigquery import load_json_into_table, full_table_name
from lib.utils.cloud_storage import load_config, read_files_in_bucket
from lib.utils.slack import create_notification_operators
from airflow.models.param import Param

# Default parameters for the task
ENV = os.environ.get("ENV")
DAG_ID = f"toy_data__ingestion__{ENV}"
PROJECT_ID = f"cat-{ENV}-toy"

# Defining the bucket to read the configuration files
CONFIG_BUCKET = f"cat-{ENV}-toy/products/ref_data"
CONFIG_FILENAME = "toy_ref_data.yaml"

# Load Config
CONFIG = load_config(bucket_path=CONFIG_BUCKET, filename=CONFIG_FILENAME)


logging.info(f"##### The overall config loaded for {DAG_ID} has been loaded")


REGION = CONFIG["region"]
DATASET = CONFIG["dataset_id"]

default_dag_args = {
    "owner": "fancybear",
    "retries": 1,
    "project_id": PROJECT_ID,
    "region": REGION,
}


with DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_ID,
    start_date=datetime(2023, 2, 12),
    max_active_runs=1,
    schedule=None,
    default_args=default_dag_args,
    params={
        "tables_to_ingest": Param(
            [], 
            type="array",
        ),
    },
    catchup=False,
    tags=["toy", "ball"],
) as trigger_dag:
    @task
    def load_data(**context):
        file_names = [
            f"{file_name}.yaml" for file_name in context["params"]["tables_to_ingest"]
        ]
        TABLE_CONFIGS = [
            yaml.safe_load(
                read_files_in_bucket(
                    bucket_path=(CONFIG_BUCKET + "/schemas"), matching_filename=file
                )[0]
            )
            for file in file_names
        ]
        for config in TABLE_CONFIGS:
            logging.info(
                f"####### Loading data into table {config['table_id']} #######"
            )
            config[
                "raw_file_path"
            ] = f"gs://{CONFIG_BUCKET}/data/{config['raw_file_name']}"

            load_json_into_table(
                config=config,
                table_id=full_table_name(PROJECT_ID, DATASET, config["table_id"]),
                region=REGION,
            )

    notify_operators = create_notification_operators(DAG_ID)

    load_data() >> notify_operators


Please share DAG definition code here

@mad_ DAG definition added

So, I am not sure how you are creating multiple DAGs using the code you shared but I am assuming you want to include DAG_ID in your tags as well based on ENV variable and therefore updating the list dynamically and adding ENV as tags should solve the problem or at least will give you a headstart
ENV='ball'
tags=["toy", ENV]


This solution will still display the tags as ball toy and not as toy ball in the UI right? Since they are sorted alphabetically
